# I need to decrypt file encrypted by gpg (in command line)

Tags: android, cryptography, aes, gnupg

I have a file, which I encrypted on PC from command line using **aes256** and a passphrase.

```
gpg --cipher-algo AES256 --output testfile.gpg --symmetric testfile.txt
```

Now I need to decrypt this file from my android application.

I had expiarance with decryption data (encrypted with aes256) in android before but then I had to provide KEY (256 bit) and a salt (128 bit) to decrypt.

How can I convert my passphrase to key/salt pair?
Or how having key/salt pair I can encrypt a file using GPG (and using the same key/salt to decrypt later)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use AESCrypt app for encryption and then I can decrypt this file on android side using standard android API (no libraries needed).

AES crypt has [documented](https://www.aescrypt.com/aes_file_format.html) its file format. They also has [open source implementation](https://www.aescrypt.com/java_aes_crypt.html) for java which allowed me to write my code.